# How to make polygons smoother

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I am designing a board using Altium Design 18.1 and I have just poured this GND polygon and it[image] looks so roughly is there any way to make it smoother?

Comment: Is this the Gerber? It may just render that way in Altium to reduce processing, but if you export to the Gerber it might still come out perfectly rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Arc approximation" value from the Polygon properties [ 1 ] is what you're looking for. Reducing this value will smooth your polygon arcs - don't forget to repour. [Check the documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-prop-polygonpourpolygon-pour-properties-ad?version=18.1#!properties) for more information.

*Side note: It's worth understanding that, based on your target PCB fabrication class and your manufacturer's process, it may not be relevant to have "absolutely accurate arcs": the etching process is somewhat rough. Finally it's a balance to find between file size and (needed) precision.*

[ 1 ]

[image: Polygon arc approximation]