# Smoothing arc shape in Altium

Tags: altium, arc

I was not able to find this topic on any official Altium documentation so maybe any of you could help me out. I have imported from other CAD tool bunch of outline shapes for NLP lines and I want to convert them in Altium into solid regions. My problem is when it comes to the converting of any arc or rounded shapes - there is given amount of precison Altium can do that, for example after converting below shape the resulting solid region looks like this:

[image]

[image]

which is quite angular comparing to original shape outline. Is there any way of increasing presision for this operation resulting in smoothing the shape? I do this from level of PCB library component editor in Altium, no PCB document itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make polygons smoother](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469793/how-to-make-polygons-smoother)

Comment: Thanks for replying but unfortunately it does not - I have seen this topic also, but they were referring to the polygons case when pouring them around vias and I need those shapes to be of mechanical/top layer soldid region/pad type in PCB library element creation.